# Why does a GPO not apply to a certain OU

Tags: group-policy

I am having an issue, where a GPO for Power Options doesn't apply to a certain OU even though I have linked it. This GPO is an exception from the Domain-Level GPO for Power Options and should only apply to the clients in this OU.

The GPO basically says to NEVER shutdown, hibernate or sleep and to also never allow the displays to go off. The problem I have is that it doesn't apply even though the GPO is listed when I perform gpresult. The client sleeps after 500 seconds.

And that is where my confusion starts, because the 500 seconds are nowhere declared, not even in the Domain-Level GPO.

When I look into the computersettings it shows, that the wanted settings are applied but it doesn't behave correctly.

I'll add pictures below so you can see exactly what I have fabricated. I hope you can help me with this issue and maybe explain the general dynamics so I can expand my knowledge about this topic.

[This is the policy that needs to apply to the OU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46huy.png)

[This is the Domain Level Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KWGC.png)

[The structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq8wr.png)

[Here is a screenshot of gpresult.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjcGz.jpg)

[and a screenshot of powersettings in registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BVnW.png)

Comment: How did you determine it's sleeping after 500 seconds? Kernel-Power events in event viewer like ID 42 will show a sleep reason like button/lid, system idle, or application which might be helpful.

Comment: On one of the problem clients, run `gpresult /scope Computer /H c:\temp\gpresult.html` and open the result file in a browser to see which GPO set each value to. Or generate an RSOP from the GPO editor

Comment: I have checked gpresult /scope and it seems that, the GPO is received from the one I need, but the settings are the ones from the domain level. 

I've checked the GPOs on the client but they are not configured. Is this correct behaviour even though the html says they have been applied?

Comment: Is the Domain-level GPO set to "Enforced"? By default, A GPO linked to a specific OU will override a domain-level GPO. Where are you checking on the client? I believe these settings mostly get added into `HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings`.

Comment: I checked on gpedit.msc but I guess that was the wrong place. 
Now I've checked the registry on the folder you said and there are 2 values: 
ACSettingIndex and DCSettingIndex but both are set to 0.

Comment: The read/edit tool for domain-level policies is `gpmc.msc` (`gpedit.msc` only shows local settings). Can you add a screenshot to your question of the power plan properties section from the gpresult.html file?

Comment: good to know! Yes I added a screenshot of it. And I also added a screenshot of the registry and realized, that the policy number of the one I want to apply is not included.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots, the GPO you want to apply is changing the settings for the power plan named "high performance", while the domain-level policy is changing settings for the plan named "balanced". They both try to set themselves as the active plan, so it might be a race condition.

You should probably use the **same** plan name if you want to overwrite the domain-level power settings.

OR, you might be able to use the `Administrative Templates\System\Power Management\`[Select an active power plan](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.PowerManagement::InboxActiveSchemeOverride_2) GPO setting instead though, which shows up in the registry here:

```
Path  = HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\
Name  = ActivePowerScheme
Value = 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c (for high-performance)
```

Comment: Both options did not work. But I want to say thank you a lot for your efforts and informations I really appreciate it!

Comment: I also want to add, that I made another observation and it seems that no client in our company seems to get the power options applied through GPOs. Not even the ones that are in another OU, where no Power-GPO is added.

 Looks to me like there is a bigger issue going on. I might have to check more in detail about what is going on. I'll keep you updated if you want :D